# How can I count item quantity per company? - queryset

Tags: django

```
class Item(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I count quantity per company?

```
quantity = 0
for item in queryset:
   quantity += item.quantity

print quantity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the quantity sum of all items for every company, you can do:

```
Company.objects.annotate(quantity_sum=Sum('item_set__quantity'))
```

The result is a queryset where every object (Company instance) has an attribute 'quantity_sum' representing the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use django aggregation [on backward relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards):

```
for company in Company.objects.annotate(total_qty=Sum('item__quantity')):
    print company, company.total_qty
```

Note, that you can use any filter on `Company` model as usual. For example:

```
us_companies = Company.objects.filter(contry='US') \
                              .annotate(total_qty=Sum('item__quantity')):
```